# GetVaryByCustomString in OWIN based ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, outputcache

I'm trying to cache an output which should by vary by the logged in user in a MVC 5 OWIN (Self Hosted) based application.

I want to know how can I override the GetVaryByCustomString method to accomplish this?